# How could I use repo-specific VIM undo directories (undodir) without revealing my path structure to everyone who clones the repo?

Tags: git, vim

I recently discovered VIM's persistent undo feature and I'm loving it because it allows me to go back and fine-tune my git commits if desired.

Currently, all my VIM undo files are simply created alongside each edited file. This works fine, but it litters the source tree. It looks unprofessional and disorganized.

So I came across a setting to use in my local (project-specific) `.vimrc` that allows me to store all undo files in a directory relative to the working directory. This would be perfect except for the way VIM then chooses to name these files - which is to use the full path to create the file name in order to ensure uniqueness. Clearly this feature was intended for specifying a directory such as `~/.vimundo` to keep the undo files of multiple projects. However, that's not how I want to use it. I want it on a per-project basis without having to worry about the rest of the system.

.vimrc:

```vimscript
set undodir=./.vimundo/
set undofile
```

That results in something like this being created inside my project's `./.vimundo` directory for each edited file in my project (this one is for my project's `.vimrc`):

`%home%douglas%Projects%auto_gen_projects%cmake_project_files%.vimrc`

That's nearly perfect except I want the filename to be created from the relative path. I might want to reorganize my projects without losing or having to rename the undo files. Additionally, I don't want strangers to have knowledge of my personal file structure when I push the repo.

Is there an effective way to separate undo files from the source tree without the obligation VIM creates from the way it chooses to name files when setting the `undodir` option?

Or is there a better way for accomplishing what I want, which is simply to use project-specific, location-independent undo files that don't offend the presentation of my source tree while still keeping them in the repo?

Comment: So you commit your undo files into Git? Why don't you use Git (private branches, stashes) to be able to "go back and fine-tune my commits"? That would make far more sense to me; I see undo as short-term and ephemeral, and Git as long-term and permanent.

Comment: @IngoKarkat Thanks, I'm using a private branch called dev with the master branch ignoring undo files. I then `git checkout master`, `git cherry-pick -n dev`, `git reset HEAD`, `git ignore clean -Xf` and finally `git commit --reuse-message=dev`. I'm keeping the undo files while I get more comfortable with new design patterns and features of C++. I might edit my exact process and setup into the question or provide an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. As nobody else has already answered this, I've put my opinion into one. Feel free to contribute what you've finally settled on, too!

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend to use Git (private branches, stashes, or something like that - Git is very accommodating here) to be able to "go back and fine-tune my commits"? That would make far more sense to me; I see undo as short-term and ephemeral, and Git as long-term and permanent.

I had commented that already, and after your confirmation, I think I've found what at least for me would amount to a shopstopper: **Vim's undo tracks all changes, with no possibility to edit those**. Now imagine you accidentally paste a password, or access token, or URL of an adult website into Vim *(I do that all the time - the accidental pasting, that is)*, immediately undo that, but it would still be accessible through your persistent undo (as Vim does not only keep a sequential history, but the full branches). You'd have to explicitly clean the undo history (`:set ul=-1`), or hope that enough (1000 by default) further edits happen so that the change gets evicted from history prior to committing them.

Once committed to Git (and pushed to a public location like *GitHub*), the changes are basically a public record, and hard if not impossible to get rid of again. Though the possibility of an actual "attack" against you is small, I would not use such a process.

#### Alternatives

If you don't want to store your intermediate changes as Git artifacts, there are other possibilities to store certain versions for some time. For example, my [writebackup plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1828) provides a lightweight versioning system that does not interfere with Git at all (you can store the backups outside the working copy, or git-ignore the backup files or a dedicated backup dir that collects all backups from inside the working copy).